# Can you tag generated SQL from an ORM for troubleshooting purposes?

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, llblgen

We heavily use ORMs in our web application (EF and LLBlGen) and we have a DBA helping us improve the performance of the application by finding queries that are causing the most problems. We have a lot of linq queries accessing the database and some are quite complex.

Is there a way to tag the generated SQL with some identifier from Linq queries so that if the DBA finds some bad sql we can then easily go find the linq statements that generated it.

Comment: [Logging and intercepting database operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception)

Comment: Yes, you can use TagWith

Comment: @ErikEJ Yes, they can, but only *if* they are using EF *Core* version *X+*. You always seem to assume people are using the "latest and greatest", which in the real application development world is not true in most of the cases. Nothing in this question indicates they use EF Core or EF Core version which supports tagging, so it's good to ask that first.

Comment: Sorry if I offended you, and agree that the question is not tagged EF Core.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @ErikEj for pointing me in the write direction. For EF Core I can use Query Tags https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tags

For LLBLGen I can use the MarkWithTag() extension method they provide for IQueryable. https://www.llblgen.com/Documentation/5.5/LLBLGen%20Pro%20RTF/Using%20the%20generated%20code/Linq/gencode_linq_generalusage.htm#query-tagging

Entity Framework appears more difficult and doesn't have a specific method to achieve the desired outcome and required adding a redundant select or where clause. [How to "tag" Entity Framework Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33834460/how-to-tag-entity-framework-queries)

Comment: See the duplicate I tacked to the question you refer to.

Comment: @Gert Arnold that answer works in debugging but in a prod environment logging all the SQL calls could add a performance overhead compared to adding a piece of identifying text to a query that can then be referred to by a DBA using their tooling.

Comment: True. Our line of defense here is to match the time expensive queries were logged with the application's logging data and see what users were doing at that moment. Then we start a debugging session (in dev environment) trying to reproduce the query. I must add we hardly ever need it. Matching these logs is often enough to find the source of the query right away.